# Who was the oldest pilot ever so far?

Tags: pilots, aviation-history

Based on any historical records, who has been the oldest pilot ever? "Pilot", I mean, somebody who managed to take off, return to the airport and land without  help. That much is probably not possible without training; would still be interesting to know if this pilot had a valid or maybe expired license.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Cole Kugel, 105**

> Born March 14, 1902, Cole Kugel, a resident of Longmont, Colorado, USA is the oldest qualified pilot. He was born one year before the legendary Wright Brothers took to the skies, and has been flying ever since. Kugel earned his pilot's license in 1945 and flew in 2007 for the last time, aged 105, piloting in the company of local veterinarian Lynn Ferguson in his beloved 1976 Cessna 182.

http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/records-1000/oldest-qualified-pilot/

[image]
<sup>*2005 Photo: Daily Times-Call | Hunter McRae*</sup>

Comment: He's been flying ever since he was born? Impressive.

Comment: I showed this to my father and he said, hmmm, only 23 more years to pass him, the old coot.

Comment: @fooot Not only he was flying since he was born, but even before Wright Brothers invented an airplane.

Comment: Apparently the oldest person to earn a pilot's license was 87 at the time - [some interesting "oldest pilot" records over at Guinness](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/Search.aspx?q=Oldest+Pilot)!

Comment: @voretaq7 link is N/G